# Amp-shadow streaming no rendering until stream complete

Tags: streaming, amp-html, shadow-dom

I'm having an issue with streaming into a shadowDom with  AMP.attachShadowDocAsStream.

my set is almost identical to the example in the AMP docs:

```
const shadowDoc = AMP.attachShadowDocAsStream(ampContainer, url, {});

shadowDoc.writer.onBodyChunk(function(){
  console.log('chunk added');
});

fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'}).then(response => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  function readChunk() {
    console.log('chuck recieved');
    return reader.read().then(chunk => {
      let text = decoder.decode(
        chunk.value || new Uint8Array(),
        {stream: !chunk.done});
      if (text) {
        shadowDoc.writer.write(text);
      }
      if (chunk.done) {
        shadowDoc.writer.close();
      } else {
        return readChunk();
      }
    });
  }
  return readChunk();
});
```

The requested url returns simply:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-docformat="amp" ⚡>
  <head></head>
  <body id="body">
  <% for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { %>
    <div>
      <h1><strong><%= i %></strong> - This is a load of self contained data</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Although I can see from the console.log that the shadowDoc.writer is adding chunks to the node (also the page increases in size, as apparent from the scroll bar). The dom content doesn't render until shadowDoc.writer.end() is called, thus negating the whole point in streaming html in the first place.

Can the dom be forced to render each chunk as it is added?

Comment: Could you please share what browser you are using? That will help attempt to reproduce. Firefox unfortunately does not yet support streaming and incremental parsing of JS-created documents https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867102

Comment: Tested in Chrome and Chrome Canary, neither rendered until shadowDoc.writer.close() is called, infact removing the shadowDoc.writer.close() function call prevents anything from rendering